# jQuery mobile using data-role in jQuery.html

Tags: jquery

I have an web app which is HTML5 compliant and caches so I can work off line.

I have javascript to read in data and set upo in a page which displays fine

How can I get jQuery " data-role " commands in HTML tags to function when they are added to the page with javascript using jQuery.html.  At the moment they are ignored.

data-role commands work OK when in directly in HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger the "create"-event.

```
$('#pageId').trigger("create");
```

That will cause jQuery mobile to enhance the page.

Comment: I am currently using jQuery.live and not trigger.  I shall try

Comment: I have tried trigger and no difference. data-role still ignored

Comment: Can you give some example code or something? So I can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do..